# Do I need unique ApplicationId to publish an app?

Tags: flutter, google-play, app-store

BundleId such as `Reversed Domain + project name`. Is it required to publish an app? If so, what could be the most efficient way to get one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is yes you need an ApplicationId to publish the app on the store both for iOS and Android.

You can choose one not used before by you or from others apps on the store.

You can use different ApplicationId for Android and iOS.

For android, you can add your application id in the application `build.gradle` like following

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myapp"
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

for iOS you have to create one in the developer console and add it in XCode. can you see:

- https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/DevPortalGuide/CreatingandConfiguringAppIDs/CreatingandConfiguringAppIDs.html
- https://support.staffbase.com/hc/en-us/articles/115003535352-Creating-the-iOS-App-ID

I hope that is useful for you.